# Is there any way to check superposition in a source of photons?

Tags: photons, polarization, superposition

Suppose we are given a box containing 10 photons. We only know that the box contains:

- 5 horizontally and 5 vertically polarized photons

**or**

- 5 left-circular and 5 right-circular polarized photons.

Is it possible to distinguish which box was given?

My first thought was to say: No! Because the polarization in the first box and the ones in the second box are not linearly independent, thus in this case a measure would give components in the horizontal direction and/or in the vertical direction in such a way that an experimenter A could say "*there are x% of photons in the H polarization and y% in the V polarization*" and he would be 'right', but another experimenter B could say that the photons are circularly polarized and he can only measure H and V polarization and he would be 'right' as well.

Am I wrong?

Is this has anything to do with Quantum State Tomography?

I mean, to distinguish between the two cases would I need to measure in another basis? But there are any basis (some rotated one?) which could give the right answer?

That's the first question.
The second one is:

In a more general case: Suppose you are give two sources. How to check whether one of them is a superposition of the other?

Comment: I really like the problem about whether we can distinguish the two boxes. An early answer of mine discusses to what extent the answer is yes: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/645150/

Comment: With 5 horizontally and 5 vertically polarized photons you could have 10 circularly all one way and 0 circularly the other .... or any mix there of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your first question:

> Can we distinguish the states $| 5_H 5_V \rangle$ and $| 5_L 5_R \rangle$?

Yes, by measuring in the $\{H, V \}$-basis. For the $| 5_H 5_V \rangle$ state it's clear that in this basis we see 5 horizontally and 5 vertically polarized photons. But what about the $| 5_L 5_R \rangle$ state? For this, we have to transform it into the $\{H, V \}$-basis. We can write the state in terms of [creation operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creation_and_annihilation_operators) $\hat{a}_i^\dagger$ as
$$| 5_L 5_R \rangle = \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{5!}} \left( \hat{a}_L^\dagger \right)^5 \right) \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{5!}} \left( \hat{a}_R^\dagger \right)^5 \right) | 0 \rangle. \tag{1}$$
Now we use the fact that [the creation operators for left- and right-handed circular polarization can be expressed in terms of the creation operators for horizontal and vertical polarization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_polarization#Circular_polarization):
$$\hat{a}_L^\dagger = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( \hat{a}_H^\dagger -i \hat{a}_V^\dagger \right), \quad
\hat{a}_L^\dagger = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( \hat{a}_H^\dagger +i \hat{a}_V^\dagger \right) \tag{2}$$
Inserting $(2)$ into $(1)$ and multiplying out, we get
$$\begin{split}| 5_L 5_R \rangle &= \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{5! \, 2^5}} \left( \hat{a}_H^\dagger -i \hat{a}_V^\dagger \right)^5 \right) \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{5! \, 2^5}} \left( \hat{a}_H^\dagger +i \hat{a}_V^\dagger \right)^5 \right) | 0 \rangle \\
&= \frac{1}{5! \, 2^5} \left( \left( \hat{a}_H^\dagger \right)^{10} + 5 \left( \hat{a}_H^\dagger \right)^8 \left( \hat{a}_V^\dagger \right)^2 + 10 \left( \hat{a}_H^\dagger \right)^6 \left( \hat{a}_V^\dagger \right)^4 \\
\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad + 10 \left( \hat{a}_H^\dagger \right)^4 \left( \hat{a}_V^\dagger \right)^6 + 5 \left( \hat{a}_H^\dagger \right)^2 \left( \hat{a}_V^\dagger \right)^8 + \left( \hat{a}_V^\dagger \right)^{10} \right) | 0 \rangle.\end{split}$$
As you can see, the amplitude to detect 5 vertical or horizontal photons is $0$. For this specific state, you only get even numbers of photons of each polarization. I think, this is not exactly what you intended to ask, judging from your second question.

---

Let me rephrase your second question:

> If we don't know in which basis a state is prepared, can we still find out what the state is?

Here, the answer is no. At least not in a single-shot experiment.<sup>1</sup> You have to prepare the state many times and measure it in different bases. And that is, as you mention in your question, quantum state tomography. As an example: Imagine a molecule in a crystal, which emits linearly polarized light, but you don't know the direction of polarization. The state of a single photon emitted by this molecule can be written as
$$| 1_\theta \rangle = \cos \theta \, |1_H \rangle + \sin \theta \, |1_V \rangle.$$
With just $1$ photon, all you can do is detect it in a random polarization basis. Then you get a click or you don't. This gives you a hint what polarizations are more likely, but you are nowhere close to *knowing* what the polarization is. So you do the experiment a second time and again get a click or not. You can update the probability distribution of possible polarizations accordingly, but there are still infinitely many polarizations that lead to the observed results with a finite probability. If you keep repeating the experiment, the probability distribution gets sharper and at some point you are fine with the remaining uncertainty and stop the experiments.

Practically, you measure the number of photons passing through a horizontally oriented polarizer, then you rotate the polarizer a bit and measure the photons again. You continue rotating the polarizer and measuring the photon rate until you spanned all angles. Then you fit a $\cos^2 \left( \alpha_\text{polarizer} - \theta \right)$ to the data and extract the polarization angle $\theta$ from it.
[image]

<sup>1</sup>This is why the [BB84](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BB84) quantum cryptography protocol works.

Comment: I am not sure if i get it what you meant with $ | 5_L 5_R \rangle $: is it the notation for product state?

Anyways, you say "Yes, by measuring in the {H,V}-basis." to my first question. So you are telling me that just measuring in the {H, V} basis I'm able to distinguish which box I received? Since I don't know a priori the content of the box, measuring in the {H,V} basis will give me H and V results, for either box, which will let me conclude that I have the H,V box always.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, for the second questions it was what I was looking for. Very useful and clear explanation. Thanks!

Comment: @Dimitri Yes, the $|5_L5_R\rangle$ is short-hand notation for $|5_L\rangle\otimes|5_R\rangle$, i.e. a product state of 5 left- and 5 right-handed circularly polarized photons.
And yes, I actually claim that you can distinguish the two boxes by measuring in the $\{H,V\}$ basis. For the $|5_L5_R\rangle$ state you will only get a result out of $\{(0,10),(2,8),(4,6),(6,4),(8,2),(10,0)\}$, but never $(5,5)$. (The first number is the number of photons detected with $H$ polarization, the second the number of photons with $V$ polarization.) But that it works out like that is specific to the state.